# Embeding Aws Quicksight Dashboard on website getting error Access Denied for root

Tags: amazon-web-services

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Roles may not be assumed by root accounts.
How to solve the issue.

Example:

`aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::293424211206:role/QuickSightEmbed" --role-session-name tom.smith@example.com`

`aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::293424211206:role/QuickSightEmbed" --role-session-name tom.smith@example.com`

Answer (score 1):

This is an appropriate error to receive; root doesn’t need to assume any role, it has total access.

Considering the security implications of using root credentials, you should not use root credentials for anything except rare cases when you genuinely need root access, and you certainly should not use root credentials in a web app where they might be exposed.

Instead, create an IAM user with the appropriate permissions to assume the role you want to assume and use this new IAM users credentials in your application.